# Using Appium Driver with Python Test Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, appium

I've refactored my script several times to get it working and now getting and error. Please can someone help me to understand what actually is displaying on screen and where am I going wrong?

Im getting these errors each time running it inside the terminal.

test_login_valid_password (**main**.HmaAndroidLoginTest) ... ERROR
test_login_valid_username (**main**.HmaAndroidLoginTest) ... ERROR

======================================================================

### ERROR: test_login_valid_password (**main**.HmaAndroidLoginTest)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Android01.py", line 13, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 37, in **init**
    super(WebDriver, self).**init**(command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 87, in **init**
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 136, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 194, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 463, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError:

======================================================================

### ERROR: test_login_valid_username (**main**.HmaAndroidLoginTest)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Android01.py", line 13, in setUp
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 37, in **init**
    super(WebDriver, self).**init**(command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 87, in **init**
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 136, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 194, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 463, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError:

---

Ran 2 tests in 0.014s

FAILED (errors=2)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I figured that it was a case that the Appium Server wasn't running and each time you run a new set of tests, you must refresh the Appium Server.

Also tidying up the script, the tests passed.